# How to verify Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) 3.x?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, verification

Downloading

- `sha256sums.txt`
- downloading one or more signatures
- the archive itself

Then verifying each signature one by one. Then creating the sha256 of the archive. Then looking into the `sha256sums.txt` file if the sha256 sum matches. These are a lot steps. Kinda more cumbersome than verifying TBB 2.x (where you just verify the archive with a signature).

Can the required steps be reduced a bit without sacrificing security? Is `shasums --check` helpful?

If you want, feel free to edit this question and make it Linux/CLI specific if its too broad.

Comment: Could you please include the links to these files? They are not in `/dist` of the Tor site.

Comment: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-bundle-30alpha4-released https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/3.0a4/

Answer (score 1):

This could be scripted.

```
!/bin/sh

d=https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/3.0a4/
z=TorBrowserBundle-3.0-alpha-4-osx32_de.zip

wget --no-check-certificate $d/$z
wget --no-check-certificate $d/sha256sums.txt
for u in dcf erinn gk ln5 mp
do
    wget --no-check-certificate $d/sha256sums.txt.$u-asc
done 

verified=1
for asc in *-asc
do
    gpg --verify $asc sha256sums.txt
    v=$?
    [[ $v -eq 0 ]] && verified=0
done

if [[ $verified -eq 0 ]]
then
    t=$(mktemp -t sha)
    grep $z sha256sums.txt > $t
    shasum -c $t
    rm $t
else
    echo no signature could be verified
fi
```

This works on Mac OS X with all the tools installed from MacPorts.

Comment: Note that using gpg's exit code is not a reliable indication of whether things are all great or not.  Might be better to use --status-fd and look for VALID_SIG.  Maybe even with the fingerprints we expect.  If you write a /bin/sh script you should probably not use bashisms such as [[.  Also, please quote your variables, thanks :)